# Entity Framework database first does not catches sql Raiserror at the end of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, entity-framework, exception

I've been googling around and I have found similar questions but not exactly this case.
I have a sql server 2005 stored procedure which raises an error at the end, after any data processing call.

```
    Create Procedure webzTest(
      @nClaPais Int
    )
    As
    Begin 

        Select * From zPais Where ClaPais = @nClaPais
        Raiserror('TEST ERROR!!!', 16, -1)  
    End
```

On the client side Entity Framework (Visual Studio 2012) tries to catch the exception, but it ignores it.

```
    public static void webzTestTransaction()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyWebEntities())
        {
            using (var trx = MyTransactionScope.newTransactionScope())
            {
                var connection = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Connection;
                connection.Open();  // Open connection explicitly to avoid EF closing and reopening which invokes DTC
                try
                {
                    ctx.webzTest(1).ToList();
                    ctx.webzTest(2).ToList();
                    trx.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The raised error is ignored.
If I put the Raiserror() statement BEFORE the Select then the exception is catched by EF code, but I expect the same behaviour in the above code.

Let me add a similar example using ADO.NET. In ths case, the exception is catched as expected:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlTransaction trx = null;
        try
        {
            trx = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "webzTest";
            cmd.Transaction = trx;

            var parClaPais = new SqlParameter("@nClaPais", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parClaPais);

            parClaPais.Value = 1;
            SqlDataReader result1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            parClaPais.Value = 2;
            SqlDataReader result2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            trx.Commit();
            trx = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (trx != null)
                trx.Rollback();

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Then: What is wrong with EF? or Which is the rule to follow in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this thread http://forums.asp.net/t/1164613.aspx?TRY+CATCH+block+not+cetching+RAISERROR+

Comment: Pawel, thanks for your response. In that thread the problem was the Raiserror severity level at 10. This case the severity is 16. It should raise an error back to C# code. Actually it raises the error correctly 'cause it is cached by the ADO.NET code. But why the EF code ignores it?

Comment: There's no catch in your first example, is that intended?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did it intentionally. The exception is to be catched higher in the code hierarchy.

Comment: I added the catch block to webzTestTransaction() to emphasize the problem